# PHP json_encode. How to show number string value without quote?

Tags: php, gmp

I use gmp_init so that I can use big number. Is it possible to show the value without double quote after json encoding?

```
<?php
$data = ['key' => gmp_strval(gmp_init('0x6252f8774def5e344'))];
echo json_encode($data); // {"key":"113359973681592656708"}

result:{"key":"113359973681592656708"}
expect:{"key":113359973681592656708}
```

Do I need to create my custom json_encode method?

---

Update 1

JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK is close but it reduces some precision.

```
<?php
$data = ['value' => gmp_strval(gmp_init('0x6252f8774def5e344'))];
echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); // {"value":1.1335997368159e+20}
```

---

Update 2

When I used gmp_intval, unexpected number was showed.. losed precision..?

```
<?php
$data = ['value' => gmp_intval(gmp_init('0x6252f8774def5e344'))];
echo json_encode($data); // {"value":2679509239335347012}
```

---

Update 3

I'm now making a public API. This API returns big value as number. I'm refering to this API.

```
$ curl -s https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs/0x3f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be/balance
{
  "address": "3f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be",
  "total_received": 1869632244986662686850430,
  "total_sent": 1856002482088823771866944,
  "balance": 13629762897838914983486,
  "unconfirmed_balance": -201611713184000000000,
}
```

Comment: `gmp_strval` you are converting it into string.

Comment: use `gmp_intval()`. But if the number is too big for a PHP integer, that won't work. It will probably be too big for the receiver of the JSON as well.

Comment: @nogad is there any upper limit to the number in JSON, if not then how is it an invalid JSON `{"key":113359973681592656708}`

Comment: The whole point of using GMP is that it allows you to work with numbers that are bigger than the normal integers that PHP allows.

Comment: There's no upper limit in JSON, but most languages have limits on the sizes of their integers, so they won't be able to decode it if it contains an integer they don't support.

Comment: Or they might convert it to a floating point number, losing some precision.

Comment: If you try to parse your desired JSON in Javascript, you get `{"key":113359973681592660000}`. Notice how the last few digits were lost.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm now trying your suggestions one by one.

Comment: I'm making JSON API. I'm still not sure which is the suitable response type between string value or numeric.

Comment: If it's bigger then `PHP_INT_MAX` then ... yea what they said ^

Comment: What is the client application supposed to do if the number is too big for their language?

Comment: I'm making public APIs. I never thought about the issue.